# Developing for Actions on Google in Brazilian Portuguese

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible to develop for Actions on Google in Brazilian Portuguese?

Thank you!

Comment: Updated my answer with some good news for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated - 15 Nov 2017**

Google [just announced](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/help-users-find-interact-re-engage-with.html) that *pt-BR* is now a supported locale.

**Original Answer**

Not yet. They recently announced that French, Spanish, "and other languages" would be available later this year, but no specific time frame has been announced.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you expect. You can use Brazilian Portuguese to :

- Develop applications on API.AI
- Develop applications only for test purposes in Actions on Google
- Test your application through the simulator by typing your requests in brazilian portuguese in the simulator.

But what you can't do for now :

- Use [localization](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/l10n-best-practices) to localize your application in Brazilian portuguese (as the simulator does not provide the ability to have a pt-BR localized device)
- Test your application in Brazilian portuguese on your Google Home device or using voice in the Simulator

So if you want to develop an application in Brazilian Portuguese in order to be ready when the language will be available, nothing is impossible. But there are several limitations.